# Solr how get top keyword without common words

Tags: solr

I am using Solr and I would like to get the top 10 keywords of all my dataset, without the common words (like "I", "go", "the"...).

I used the "facet.excludeTerms", but there is too much to list all the common words in the query.

For now, I used the facet parameters in my query :

```
 http://localhost:8983/solr/<my_core>/select?facet=true&facet.field=content&facet.limit=10&facet.minCount=1&facet.excludeTerms=I,go,the&q=content:(%2A)&rows=1
```

My dataset can contain data from many different languages (English, French, Spanish...), so I can't use the OpenNLPTokenizer in my schema, because it is language specific, and I don't know in advance what language is gonna be inserted.

I'm also trying something with tf-idf, but nothing right for now.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/<my_core>/select?fl=idf(content,'covid')&idf(content,'and')&tf(content,'covid')&tf(content,'covid')&q=*:*&fl=score&debugQuery=true
```

I don't understand the mean of idf :

- "covid" gets 5.2 -> interesting word - OK
- "and" gets 7.3   -> common word - KO

No really big difference between the 2 values, so how can I use them ?

And all tf values are 0 :(.

Any idea please ?

Comment: But, shouldn't you precisely use the [language detection](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/indexing-guide/language-detection.html) feature ? It would allow to index the content of any document in a text fieldType specific to the language detected and thus to obtain better results, ie. stopwords would be discarded properly at index time (see [Stop Filter](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/indexing-guide/filters.html#stop-filter)), and you wouldn't have to bother with it for your stats.

Comment: One important thing I forgot to mention is that the field norm plays a decisive role in how TF-IDF behaves, so you might want to check if length normalization is enabled on your field, see `omitNorms`, and for the tf values check `omitTermFreqAndPositions`, https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/indexing-guide/fields.html#optional-field-type-override-properties. Also, first you could try to check the output of `termFreq()` and `docFreq()` to see if it is what you expect (ie. termFreq is human readable, tf is a "similarity" factor specific to the field used for scoring).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your anwsers Eric. I already used termFreq() & docFreq(), but not what I needed for this part. About your first comment, if I use the language detection, I suppose I will have by example the French documents in the field "text_fr" & the English documents in the "text_en".., so not possible then to query on one unique field and get the mixed keywords (French & English), right ?

Comment: I will try with omitNorms, nothing tested with this for now, thank for the advice !

Comment: I meant that `termFreq()` and `tf()` are two different functions (probably because I thought it was an alias!). It's possible to query multiple fields, but yes tf is specific to one single field. Though the problem you might encounter, by having only one field that mixes several languages, is that a stopword in a given lang could be a meaningful word in another one, in which case there is a risk of either missing potential top terms if you choose to discard them, or having stopwords in lang x biasing the frequency of the meaningful terms in lang y otherwise.